# How to add line breaks to a blockquote in RestructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

This quote:

```
    "there are worse things
    than being alone
    but it often takes
    decades to realize this
    and most often when you do
    it's too late
    and there's nothing worse
    than too late"

    -- Charles Bukowski
```

Is rendered like:

```
“there are worse things than being alone but it often takes decades to realize this and most often when you do it’s too late and there’s nothing worse than too late”
—Charles Bukowski
```

I have found that [a raw HTML replacement can be used to force a blockquote](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#how-to-indicate-a-line-break-or-a-significant-newline) but it doesn't work within a blockquote.

Is there any way to use line breaks in a blockquote?

Comment: I'd love to upvote you just for the Bukowski quote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use [line blocks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks).

To create one, simply prefix each line with a vertical bar ("|") like so:

```
| "there are worse things  
| than being alone  
| but it often takes  
| decades to realize this  
| and most often when you do  
| it's too late  
| and there's nothing worse  
| than too late"

-- Charles Bukowski
```

It should render like this:

```
"there are worse things
than being alone
but it often takes
decades to realize this
and most often when you do
it's too late
and there's nothing worse
than too late"

-- Charles Bukowsk
```